# Manjaro KDE vscode icon

Tags: icons, kde, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I have a fresh Manjaro KDE installation. For my daily programming I use Visual Studio Code, so I installed it via community pacman package `code`. Everything works smoothly. The title of the window is `Code - OSS` if that changes anything.

The one thing that bothers me is the icon on the taskbar. I am used to see blue/green vs icon, but now I see something like this:

[image]

It really bugs me, cuz I want to know exactly where my editor is. Now I have to lose time looking at the taskbar to find it. When I have a normal icon, I just see it instantly. Plus the usual one looks lovely compared to this one.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

That's the *open source* build of VSCode, and as such, doesn't use the microsoft design and registered Visual Studio icon. Use it normally.

It also happens with Google Chrome: you can install Chromium, the *open source* build of Chrome, and even authenticate and sync your settings to Chrome. But name and icon won't be the same.

If you're really into the icon and name thing, you can get the Microsoft-compiled VSCode from AUR.